# Linker error for overloaded typecast into string in class

Tags: c++, string, cross-compiling, linker-errors, abi

it seems I am having a linking problem. In my project im using a class that is defined in a header file, whose methods´ definitions lie in a precompiled library. I am using CMake and the compiling command includes the path to the precompiled library set correctly by the -L compiler flag.

The linking problem relates to an overloaded typecast.  In the header file, the overloaded typecaset looks like this:

```
namespace comm {

   struct InstanceID{
       .
       .
      __attribute__ ((visibility("default"))) operator ipl::string () const;
  }
}
```

and as mentioned, the definition lies in a precompiled library. I peeked inside the precompiled library using the `nm` linux took and the reference is indeed defined there:

> 00080ead T comm::InstanceID::operator
> std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits,
> std::allocator >abi:cxx11 const

[image]

Note that in C string is a typecast of std:basic_string<char, traits, allocator>

The linking error that I get looks like this:

> /home/FrEspinosa/xxx/xxx/xxx/xxx/xxx/xxx/xxxxxx/include/xxx/vehicle/EcallS.hxx:252: undefined reference to `comm::InstanceID::operator std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits, std::allocator >() const'

[image]

You can note that the definition in the precompiled library includes `>[abi::cx11]`, whilst the reference shown in the error does not.

Maybe this is the error, that the reference is not exactly the same? How could I solve this? What else could it be?

Thank you!

Comment: Have you read all through [What is an undefined reference/unresolved external symbol error and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix) I don't want to close this as a duplicate because I suspect your situation is not that simple.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question

Comment: @TedLyngmo Hi thanks, your link is a good reference for linking errors, but I could not see something that could relate to my issue.

Comment: @learning_dude I suspected your problem was not covered in there but had to link to it. It's _usually_ covered in that rather massive Q&A.

Comment: @TedLyngmo main answers in linked question has 14 examples of possible causes (some are so similar that can be considered as duplicate) and IMO it covers all possibilities. Do you have any other example?

Comment: I think we are focusing too much on whether my question is duplicate or not....Maybe we could focus a bit on the output of the binary file gottten nm tool and the displayed error? Particularly in the `>ABI:cxx11` that is only present in the binary? Is it a different function, and this is why is the linker does not find the reference? What can be done about it...I'm also new to this visibility attributes...I'm not sure if they have something to do..

Comment: @MarekR That was an unusual request. If I'd have a duplicate that I _really_ was sure was a fit, I'd use it to close the question. Me: "_I don't want to close this as a duplicate because I suspect your situation is not that simple_"

Comment: The `abi:cxx11` thing is controlled by `-D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=1` (default) or `0`. If your guess is correct, you either touched this flag or used a very outdated GCC that only supports the latter option.

Comment: If that's not the case, we'll need a [mcve]: make a tiny library (~10 lines) and a tiny program that uses it, compile both (show us the commands), and see if it reproduces the error.

Comment: This is not the case. I cant create a library as this is a pre-compiled library and  I dont have the source code, plus this project is huge with many dependencies. I was able, though, to track the error to this point, where the apparent problem relates to [abi:cxx11].  When GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI is set to 0 none of the references are found . I posted [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70532831/how-to-link-to-a-function-with-abicxx11-defined-in-a-shared-library/70533272?noredirect=1#comment124686371_70533272), differently. You are welcome to contribute . Thank you all so far