# How to link to a function with [abi:cxx11] defined in a shared library?

Tags: c++, string, shared-libraries, linker-errors, abi

I am peeking into a shared library using the `nm` tool.  I have two versions of this library, and on each version, I have a definition for an overloaded typecast, namely

**Version 1**

> *FrEspinosa@computerLinux:~**frameworkPath1**/lib
> $ nm -D libcomm.so | c++filt | grep comm::InstanceID::operator*
>
> 000cda80 T comm::InstanceID::operator std::__cxx11::basic_string<char,
> std::char_traits, std::allocator () const

**Version 2**

> *FrEspinosa@computerLinux:~**frameworkPath2**/lib
> $ nm -D libcomm.so | c++filt | grep comm::InstanceID::operator*
>
> 00080ead T comm::InstanceID::operator std::__cxx11::basic_string<char,
> std::char_traits, std::allocator **>[abi:cxx11]**() const

what is this this `>[abi:cxx11]`, and how should my function signature/declaration should look like in my header file, so that it matches version 2? do I need a special compiler flag, or link a special library?

As a reference, the function which links succesfully with version 1 looks like this:

```
namespace comm {

  struct InstanceID{
     .
     .
    __attribute__ ((visibility("default"))) operator ipl::string () const;
  }
}
```

EDIT:

As further reference, the compiler/linker im using is

> arm-poky-linux-gnueabi-gcc (GCC) 8.2.0

And the library was compiled with GNU 6.2.0

> FrEspinosa@computerLinux:~/**frameworkPath2**/lib $ strings  -a
> libcomm.so | grep -i gcc
>
> libgcc_s.so.1 GCC_3.5 GCC: (GNU) 6.2.0
> compilerPath/usr/lib/arm-poky-linux-gnueabi/gcc/arm-poky-linux-gnueabi/6.2.0/include

So I am using a newer compiler.

Comment: Did you get around that problem? If so, how did you do it?

I am having the same problem with a specific funtion while trying to link to Oracle's Instant Client library, and already spent half a day trying to fix the issue, without any luck so far.

Answer (score 1):

The ABI changed in C++11 which means the structure of objects and more importantly their sizes changed as well. To prevent someone to link against the old ABI, the compilers started adding the suffix `[abi:cxx11]` to the name of objects.

Which means, the library you are peeking into was compiled with a newer compiler and the one you are using is old style. You need to move into a new compiler.

Comment: I am using a newer compiler than the one it was used for the library. See edit.

Comment: Can you compile this snippet: `#include <string>

std::string getit() {
   return "Hello";
}
`
using `g++ -O3 -shared file.cpp -o file.so` and then do `nm -C file.so`.  Do you see `T getit[abi:cxx11]()` ?

Comment: I do see  `T getit[abi:cxx11]()`. Just to mention, I am using a cross compiler shown in the edit...

Comment: I tried with my cross compiler, and I also see `T getit[abi:cxx11]()`

Comment: Ok so which library does not have it? That's the library compiled with the old libs